# Compartir variables entre Clases en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo varias clases como en el ejemplo.

```
class clase1 extends padreclase1 {
 var $variable1 = 'valor1';
  var $variable2    = 'valor2';
}

class clase2 extends padreclase2 {
var $variable1  = 'valor1';
var $variable2  = 'valor2';
}
```

El valor de las variables será el mismo en todos los casos, pero no quisiera tener que repetir su escritura en todas las clases.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para meter esas variables en un fichero o similar y que luego sean insertadas al principio de cada clase? Ya que deben ser atributos de cada clase.

Comment: unos puntos, primero no veo necesaria esa sintáxis de `var` segundo si estas en el paradigma POO como lo noto, entocnes haz uso de la herencia para declararlas en una clase principal y luego deacuerdo a su modificador de acceso heredarlas y accederlas en otra clase

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. No puedo hacerlas hijas de una clase principal porque estoy usando un framework de terceros y cada una de ellas debe ser hija de unas clases ya creadas. Por eso en el ejemplo pongo padreclase1 y padreclase2.

Comment: Puedes usar una clase que sea común a ambas y tener una variable de esa clase como una propiedad dentro de las otras, usando composición en lugar de herencia

Comment: estaria bien que nos indicaras que framework estas utilizando, eso podria ayudarnos y decirte como estructurar algunas clases dependientes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para este caso, si tienes clases distintas en origen y todas las tuyas tienen que:

1.- heredar de unas clases definidas de tu framework, distintas entre si.

2.- contener atributos en cada una de ellas, iguales

la solucion es utilizar traits: http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.traits.php

por ej, en tu caso, podrias hacer:

```
trait VariablesGeneralesTrait {
    var $variable1 = 'valor1';
    var $variable2 = 'valor2';
}


use VariablesGeralesTrait;
class clase1 extends padreclase1 {
 trait VariablesGenerales;
}


use VariablesGeneralesTrait;
class clase2 extends padreclase2 {
 trait VariablesGenerales;
}
```

Con esto, se produce una "herencia lateral", de manera que todas las clases que "usen" el trait, tienen los mismos atributos (e incluso metodos).

Comment: Muchas gracias @jakaia